# How to get currently logged in user in django model on post_save signals?

Tags: django, django-models, django-signals

i want to store the information who created the object ???

trying something like this ..

```
def event_submitted(sender,instance,created,**args):
if created:
        content_type = ContentType.objects.get(app_label='activity', model='event')
        ModerationItem.objects.create(submitted_by= ?????,    # what to put here

                                      submitted_remarks=instance.remarks,
                                      activity_content_type=content_type,
                                      activity_object_id=instance.id,
                                      )


signals.post_save.connect(event_submitted , sender = Event)
```

Comment: the easy way would be to either add your procedure to the save method and use ducky typing to pass the user or add the field to the instance. Shared memory object are the other way but it's ugly and most developpers discourage it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To complement Altaisoft's answer : you have to understand that models are not dependent on HTTP requests and can be created / updated / deleted in a Python script (guess what ./manage.py loaddata do ?), a Python shell, whatever, so there's not necessarily a "logged in user".

Comment: this is what i got from my inspection .. cant get user instance in models .. Agree with u .

Answer (score 3):

Why not fill this data in your view?

```
def my_view(request):
    my_instance = Event.objects.get(pk=...)
    # Fill your instance data, for example, from a submitted form
    my_instance.submitted_by = request.user
    my_instance.save()
```

Comment: dont want to use view as i just have admin work !! i guess not possible in model ???

Comment: If you have a custom `ModelAdmin` class, you can override `save_model` function. It is responsible for saving model instances, and it gets a `request` as a variable. So, you can do what you want there. But this won't work outside your admin panel. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model